# Dealing with nested list object properties

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, deserialization

Good day everyone , I'm trying to figure out effective way to deal with these nested list objects , in this case , deserialized from XML . For example this model structure

```
public class Car 
   public property wheels as List(Of Wheels)
   public property BearingType as String 
end class

public class Wheels
   public property bearings as List(Of Bearings)
end class

public class Bearings
   public property BearingType as String 
end class
```

Let assume I deserialized 2 Car object like this

```
Car 1 (
Wheel 1 (Bearing 1 (BearingType Alloy) , Bearing 2(BearingType Alloy)
Wheel 2 (Bearing 3 (BearingType Alloy) , Bearing 4(BearingType Alloy)
)

Car 2(
Wheel 1 (Bearing 1 (BearingType Metal) , Bearing 2(BearingType Metal)
Wheel 2 (Bearing 3 (BearingType Metal) , Bearing 4(BearingType Metal)
)
```

Since I'm certain one car will have only one type of BearingType , how do I assign the bearingtype to the parent level ? So that I can access it by Car.BearingType instead of Car.Wheels(0).Bearings(0).BearingType .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the XML-structure is defined by someone else? Then I would keep it, if you are shure it will have only one then you could solve this quick and dirty:

```
Public Class Car
    Public Property wheels As List(Of Wheels)
    Public Property BearingType As String
        Get
            Return Me.wheels(0).bearings(0).BearingType()
        End Get
        Set(value As String)  
            For Each wheel In Me.wheels
                For Each bearing In wheel.bearings
                    bearing.BearingType = value
                Next
            Next
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

Or better: Implement IXmlSerializable.

Otherwise reformat the xml-files and update your classes.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Ya the xml format is predefined. I think this should be the way, but then again I'm worried about the for loop, because I need it to be quite optimized.